# Odd voting coincidences when first accessing the site after being away

Tags: discussion, community-user

As often as not when I access the site after a long time away, I get some vote within just a couple of minutes. It's almost as if someone else notices that I'm back on the site.  Does the Community User nudge some of my questions/answers when it notices that I've connected again after a layoff?

Answer (score 6):

Most likely this is just coincidence or somebody is messing with your psyche. I'm going to chalk it up to coincidence--you have a huge number of answers, and people are browsing them all of the time. Given that I have a fraction on your work and *I* get random upvotes on old answers, I can only imagine that this is a much more frequent occurence for you.

The paranoia comments reminded me of one of my favorite exchanges in *Catch-22* by Joseph Heller that I felt like sharing because what the hell. It goes (paraphrased):

> Yossarian: "They're trying to kill me!"
>
> Clevinger: "Nobody's trying to kill you!"
>
> Yossarian: "Then why are they shooting at me?"
>
> Clevinger: "They're shooting at everybody!"
>
> Yossarian: "And that makes a difference?!"

Comment: I like the "messing with his psyche" approach more! It's a stalker, tvanfosson! Hide out!

Comment: The fact that you are paranoid doesn't mean you are not being followed.

Comment: Eric, I think this is the second time I complain about to be unable to upvote your edit.

Comment: Possibly the greatest book ever.

Comment: It's still seems to be happening regularly.  I'm going to choose to believe that the system simply likes me and saves up a vote to use to welcome me back.  :-)